# ActiveMQ purge enqueued messages on create consumer

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I have a JAVA application, I need purge all enqueued messages on create consumer.

I have next code:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new         ActiveMQConnectionFactory(messageBrokerUrl);
    try {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        this.session = connection.createSession(this.transacted, ackMode);
        Destination adminQueue = this.session.createQueue(messageQueueName);

        this.replyProducer = this.session.createProducer(null);
        this.replyProducer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        //Set up a consumer to consume messages off of the admin queue
        MessageConsumer consumer = this.session.createConsumer(adminQueue);
        consumer.setMessageListener(this);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error("Error al configurar servicio de colas MQ. " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

How can i purge enqueued messages and then create the consumer, to prevent queued messages from being processed.

Answer (score 2):

The JMS API has no defined method to purge a destination so doing so using the JMS API alone isn't possible by any means other than creating a consumer on the destination and reading until you get nothing back using successive calls to `consumer.receive(1000)` or similar.

If you don't mind using the ActiveMQ objects directly then you can trying using the `destroyDestination` method in ActiveMQConnection.  This method would remove the Destination from the broker **IF** there are no active subscribers on that Destination.

Otherwise you are left with using the [JMX API](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) exposed by the ActiveMQ broker to pragmatically purge the Destination in question.